# useEffect is trigged unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, use-effect

The useEffect hook is getting called unexpectedly. Once the timer reaches zero and when I set it to 10 (using the resend Otp button), then the timer starts to decrease faster than 1 second.

My component is as follows:

```js
const EnterOtpView = ({ touched, errors, isSubmitting }) => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(3);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (timer > 0) {
            setInterval(() => setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1), 1000);
        }
    }, [timer]);

    return (
        <div>

                {timer > 0 ? (
                    <p>Resend Otp in: {timer} seconds</p>
                ) : (
                    <button
                        type='button'
                        className='btn btn-link'
                        onClick={() => setTimer(10)}
                    >
                        resend otp
                    </button>
                )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

## What I have tried:

- removed the timer from the dependencies array of useEffect
- create a separate function to reduce timer

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of how you could set an interval once, prevent it from going negative, and clear it on unmount:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Example = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(3);

  useEffect(() => {
    // setInterval returns the id of the interval so we can clear it later
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      setTimer((prevTimer) => {
        // Move our negative logic inside the functional update
        if (prevTimer > 0) {
          return prevTimer - 1;
        }
        return 0;
      })}, 1000);
    
    // Clear the interval on umount
    return () => {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {timer > 0 ? (
        <p>Resend Otp in: {timer} seconds</p>
      ) : (
        <button
          type='button'
          className='btn btn-link'
          onClick={() => setTimer(10)}
        >
          resend otp
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## The solution that worked for me:

```js
 useEffect(() => {

            setInterval(() => setTimer((prevTimer) => prevTimer - 1), 1000);

    }, []);
```

I just changed the useEffect as above, i.e. made it into the componentDidMount form of useEffect and now its working fine.

Comment: The why: Your interval callback updates `timer` which is a dependency of the `useEffect`, so the effect fires again, creating **another** interval which is also updating `timer` and they multiply. Even though each interval is only running 1 second, each second you gain more intervals. By putting it in an effect that only runs once, you only have one interval.

Comment: You should also clear the interval when the component unmounts, otherwise it will continue to run and try to update the unmounted component.

Comment: You could also re-add your logic to prevent negative numbers inside the functional update.

Comment: It would be great @BrianThompson if you could explain it with code or just psuedocode

Answer (score 0):

Remove "timer" dependency from useEffect..

It will call everytime this function whenever timee